# module creation in suiteCRM

Tags: module, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am using SuiteCRM ( Sugar CRM 6.x community edition ) &  want to create a custom login page and after successful login I want to redirect based on user type

tried to create some modules but there is no clear documentation except few of useful **[links](http://alanstorm.com/sugar_crm_hello_world)**, below are my queries :

- Can we create custom modules without using module builder, if yes then what would be steps?
- Do we need to write module in /module folder or   /custom/module folder or on both place?

any link is also appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a custom Login Page by modfying "modules/Users/login.tpl"

Custom Modules can be created through Modulebuilder or manually.

When creating modules manually it's important to use the right names.
The easiest way is a Plural name for the folder, table and Module and a singular name for the class.

Manual steps:

You need a Folder in modules/ named like you module (i.e. CAccounts)

In this folder you need a file named like the class (i.e CAccount.php) with something like that as content:

```
require_once('data/SugarBean.php');
require_once('include/utils.php');

class CAccount extends SugarBean{

    var $table_name = 'caccounts';
    var $object_name = 'CAccount';
    var $module_dir = 'CAccounts';
    var $new_schema = true;
    var $name;

    var $created_by;
    var $id;
    var $deleted;
    var $date_entered;        
    var $date_modified;        
    var $modified_user_id;  
    var $modified_by_name;

    function CAccount (){
        parent::SugarBean();
    }

    function get_summary_text(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    function bean_implements($interface)
    {
        switch($interface)
        {
            case 'ACL':return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

In this folder you need a vardefs.php file:

```
$dictionary['CAccount'] = array(
    'table'=>'caccounts',
    'audited'=>false,
    'fields'=>array (
          //Your fielddefs here     
     )
);  

require_once('include/SugarObjects/VardefManager.php');
VardefManager::createVardef('CAccounts','CAccount', array('basic'));
```

For the language and metadata folders look at any other module.

Next is a file at "custom/Extension/application/Ext/Include/CAccounts.include.php"

```
$moduleList[] = 'CAccounts'; 
$beanList['CAccounts'] = 'CAccount';        
$beanFiles['CAccount'] = 'modules/CAccounts/CAccount.php';
```

A language file for the module name must be in "custom/Extension/application/Ext/Language/"

```
$app_list_strings['moduleList']['CAccounts'] = 'Custom Accounts';
```

To display the Module in your tabs you need to use "rebuild and repair" and then the "Display Modules and Subpanels" option in the admin menu.

For a custom module you don't need the "custom/" folder structure. Files there will be used by sugar if provided, but often there's no need for that in a custom module.

Guides about the Module Framework can be found on the sugarcrm support site:
http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/03_Module_Framework

Comment: Thanks for quick response.I m looking into this